# Handling disabled select options in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need to select from a dropdown with Puppeteer - the option is not important but is required to submit the form. Problem is that the dropdown may contain several disabled options and I can't seem to exclude these.

This is to add an item with options to the cart in a test checkout. The add to cart button is disabled until the correct options are selected.

As the options select is dynamic and changes for every product I have no way of knowing which of the options are enabled and in stock.

I've originally tried to select first item selectedindex = 1, then also tried to use a variety of methods to exclude attributes:

```
const option = (await page.$x(
    '//*[@id = "selectID"]/option[disabled=null]'
  ))[0];
const value = await (await option.getProperty('value')).jsonValue();
await page.select('#selectID', value);



<select name="Color" id="selectID" pseudoid="1" class="select" style="border: 1px solid lightgray; width: 190px;" selectedindex="0"><option value="-1">- Select -</option>

<option id="opt-0" outofstock="true" value="0" disabled="disabled" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">Black[out of stock]</option>

<option id="opt-1" outofstock="true" value="1" disabled="disabled" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">Blue[out of stock]</option>

<option id="opt-2" outofstock="true" value="2" disabled="disabled" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">Red[out of stock]</option>

<option id="opt-3" outofstock="true" value="3" disabled="disabled" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">Chocolate[out of stock]</option>

<option id="opt-4" value="4" style="color: black;">Green Camouflage</option>

<option id="opt-5" outofstock="true" value="5" disabled="disabled" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">Pink Camouflage[out of stock]</option>

<option id="opt-6" value="6" style="color: black;">Arctic Blue Camouflage</option></select>
```

I would like to identify the first option which is in stock.

I can select any option based on attributes it has or even text / values but where the option does not have the text or an attribute I cannot seem to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that using the `evaluate` function:

```js
const select = await page.$("#selectID");
await page.evaluate(select => {
  for(let option of select.options)
  {
    if(!option.disabled) {
      option.selected = true;
    }
  }
}, select);
const value = await page.evaluate(select => select.value, select); 
console.log(value);
```

This will do the job on the browser side, reducing roundtrips.

If you want to select the item on the Puppeteer side you can return the option instead:

```js
const select = await page.$("#selectID");
const valueToSelect = await page.evaluate(select => {
  for(let option of select.options)
  {
    if(!option.disabled && option.id) {
      return option.value;
    }
  }
}, select);
await page.select("#selectID", valueToSelect);
const value = await page.evaluate(select => select.value, select); 
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Excellent: however it presents a new issue in that I also need to simulate a change event in order to enable the add to cart button. My previous code was as follows:

await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('#msku-sel-2').selectedIndex = 1;
    element = document.querySelector('#msku-sel-2');
    var event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
    event.simulated=true;
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
})

Comment: @AndyWilliams how about now?